# view how many people compelete the quiz on admin panel

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database and I have admin panel and I have quiz on my site.

I want to add a table to count how many people complete the quiz and show it on my admin panel

I have a questions. Is the column type `varchar` right?

What code should I type to my admin.php to show the count?

What code should I type to my EXAMPLE_QUIZ.php to send the count to database?
and what code should i add to all quiz's php files ? 
i hope someone help me :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got it. Your PHP code to increse your counter is:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$db_name    = "route";

// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE quizes SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = QUIZ_ID"; // be careful from injections again!

if($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
    echo "Done";
}else{
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}

$mysqli->close;

?>
```

Comment: should i make this default config file ? or i put it in the quiz php file ? 

and should i edit the quiz id ? i have many quiz id not only 1

Comment: you save my life ^_^ http://imgur.com/a/3OjZy

i add this connection to the quiz php files ( is there any danger ) 

one more thing 

how can i view it on my admin php 
http://imgur.com/a/LaVsL

Comment: there is error it's not going up it stay on 1 and when  go to the quiz php page i can see on top no rowsDone

Comment: I updated code. It must work correctly. 

Please send screenshots of error.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not good with programming PHP and MySQL, looks like https://stackoverflow.com/jobs is better place for this topic. Else, would be nice if you show your code and we will find a problem.

If you are going it yourself, you can use SQL query `SELECT * FROM table[ WHERE col_name = value][ AND col_name = value ] [ LIMIT count_rows, from_rows_nr ]`. And to visualize it in browser use HTML `tables` and for data get from DB use MySQL and PHP. If you connect to DB with OOP method use `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` loop and print your data.

Comment: ok but what is the type of the column in my database ( varchar ,int ) and should i make it auto increasement ?
http://www.question2answer.org/qa/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=16820872693387452051

Comment: VARCHAR is Character variable (string), so You can use it for text. 
INT is made for storing numerical variables. After you get this variable from DB you can do mathematical action with them.

If you are going just count another table you can use `SELECT COUNT(col_name) FROM table_name WHERE (put here voted peaple condition);` query. If you don't have table where is results of quiz and you need just count it. You can use 2 methosds.

1) Create ne table with only ID data type: INT and is Auto incrament
2) New table, where you store only 1 value and update it each time quiz is dome.

Comment: Do you have table where is stored data about each finished quiz?

Comment: ok i want to column ( count ) to increase it self by1 ( example : if it was 5 ) when someone complete the quiz the count column must be 6

NOTE : i have already add id and AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: no i don't have table for finished quiz?

Comment: Well if you don't have table with quiz results and all you need is count. You can create INT type collumn and make it `PRIMARY` and `AUTO_INCRAMENT` second one collumn is quiz_id (second col is neccesory only if you have multiple quiz). To know how much is votes for quiz use query `SELECT COUNT(count) FROM table_name WHERE quiz_id = quiz_id_here;`

Comment: this is my database 
http://i.imgur.com/OM9en0O.png

i want to show the result in the admin panel

Comment: while editing the ( count ) table to make it INT and AUTO_INCRAMENT

 Query error:
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: its becouse Your quizes.id is auto_incrament and primary. Just left quizes.count as INT without other parametrers.

Comment: ok  and what should i type in the QUIZ PHP to make it count ( give me the full type please :(